# Spark: Explode a dataframe array of structs and append id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently have a dataframe with an id and a column which is **an array of structs**:

```
 root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- lists: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)
```

Here is an example table with data:

```
 id | lists
 -----------
 1  | [[a, 1.0], [b, 2.0]]
 2  | [[c, 3.0]]
```

How do I transform the above dataframe to the one below? I need to "explode" the array and append the id at the same time.

```
 id | col1  | col2
 -----------------
 1  | a     | 1.0
 1  | b     | 2.0
 2  | c     | 3.0
```

---

**Edited Note:**

Note there is a difference between the two examples below. The first one contains **"an array of structs of elements"**.  While the later just contains **"an array of elements"**.

```
 root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- lists: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- amount: double (nullable = true)


root
 |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |-- b: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening Rows in Spark](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906613/flattening-rows-in-spark)

Comment: That question has a simpler dataframe where the second column is just an array.  Mine differs because my second column is an "array of structs".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`explode` is exactly the function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df.select($"id", explode($"lists")).select($"id", $"col.text", $"col.amount")
```

Comment: I simply applied what included in the solution it works just as expected by Steve. It seperates the list into individual columns. Thanx