# How to explode Spark dataframe Array field with Unique identifiers in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
+-----------+
|        f1 |
+-----------+
|[a,b,c]    |
|[e,f,g]    |
|[h,i]      |
+-----------+
```

I want to explode it to rows along with a repeated unique number field as follows:

```
+-----------+--------+
|        f1 |     uid|
+-----------+--------+
|a          |       1|
|b          |       1|
|c          |       1|
|e          |       2|
|f          |       2|
|g          |       2|
|h          |       3|
|i          |       3|
+-----------+--------+
```

I can perform explode directly as explained here - [Spark: Explode a dataframe array of structs and append id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354372/spark-explode-a-dataframe-array-of-structs-and-append-id)

but I am not sure on how to add the `uid` field to the new dataframe so that each exploded array field would have the same `uid` and other elements have different `uid` values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right way to do it, is to use `monotonically_increasing_id`

```scala
val df = Seq(Seq("a", "b", "c"), Seq("e", "f", "g"), Seq("h", "i")).toDF("f1")

df
  .withColumn("uid", monotonically_increasing_id)
  .withColumn("f1", explode($"f1"))
  .show
// +---+---+                                                                       
// | f1|uid|
// +---+---+
// |  a|  0|
// |  b|  0|
// |  c|  0|
// |  e|  1|
// |  f|  1|
// |  g|  1|
// |  h|  2|
// |  i|  2|
// +---+---+
```

The number won't necessary be consecutive as in the example, but will uniquely identify the source.

**Don't** use `rank().over(Window.orderBy("f1"))`. It is inherently sequential and not scalable and such should be avoided with exception to local `Datasets` (i.e. one which return `true` from `isLocal`).

Comment: So I find your don't... interesting. In that there is nothing but blurb on the under the hood optimization with use of DF and DS. You state the opposite, which I concur with.