# Pyspark: cast array with nested struct to string

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have pyspark dataframe with a column named **Filters**:
          "array>"

I want to save my dataframe in csv file, for that i need to cast the array to string type.

I tried to cast it: `DF.Filters.tostring()` and `DF.Filters.cast(StringType())`, but both solutions generate error message for each row in the columns Filters:

`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@56234c19`

The code is as follows

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

DF.printSchema()

|-- ClientNum: string (nullable = true)
|-- Filters: array (nullable = true)
    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
          |-- Op: string (nullable = true)
          |-- Type: string (nullable = true)
          |-- Val: string (nullable = true)

DF_cast = DF.select ('ClientNum',DF.Filters.cast(StringType())) 

DF_cast.printSchema()

|-- ClientNum: string (nullable = true)
|-- Filters: string (nullable = true)

DF_cast.show()

| ClientNum | Filters 
|  32103    | org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@d9e517ce
|  218056   | org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@3c744494
```

Sample JSON data:

```
{"ClientNum":"abc123","Filters":[{"Op":"foo","Type":"bar","Val":"baz"}]}
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you share the minimal code.

Comment: Can you print schema and show data before the transformation. Also print schema after the transformation.

Comment: The schema seems to be correct.

Comment: M not able to recreate the issue. Can you show data before the transformation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a sample JSON dataset to match that schema:

```
{"ClientNum":"abc123","Filters":[{"Op":"foo","Type":"bar","Val":"baz"}]}

select(s.col("ClientNum"),s.col("Filters").cast(StringType)).show(false)

+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ClientNum|Filters                                                           |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|abc123   |org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@60fca57e|
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Your problem is best solved using the explode() function which flattens an array, then the star expand notation:

```
s.selectExpr("explode(Filters) AS structCol").selectExpr("structCol.*").show()
+---+----+---+
| Op|Type|Val|
+---+----+---+
|foo| bar|baz|
+---+----+---+
```

To make it a single column string separated by commas:

```
s.selectExpr("explode(Filters) AS structCol").select(F.expr("concat_ws(',', structCol.*)").alias("single_col")).show()
+-----------+
| single_col|
+-----------+
|foo,bar,baz|
+-----------+
```

Explode Array reference: [Flattening Rows in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906613/flattening-rows-in-spark)

Star expand reference for "struct" type: [How to flatten a struct in a spark dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753898/how-to-flatten-a-struct-in-a-spark-dataframe#38754012)

Comment: This creates columns in the top structure rather than a single column with the contents of all the columns as a string

Comment: @alfredox Updated to add single column version.

Comment: How do we join this back to the original ids? @GarrenS

Answer (score 8):

For me in Pyspark the function [***to_json()***](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.to_json.html) did the job.

As a plus compared to the simple casting to String, it keeps the "struct keys" as well (not only the "struct values"). So for the reported example I would have something like:

```
[{"Op":"foo","Type":"bar","Val":"baz"}]
```

This was much more useful to me since that I had to write results to a Postgres table. In this format I can easily use supported JSON functions in Postgres

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with nested struct type

Answer (score -3):

You can try this:

```
DF = DF.withColumn('Filters', DF.Filters.cast("string"))
```

Comment: I tried, same result : org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeArrayData@3

Comment: I'd say you have to run UDF where you can apply some logic to convert array to string and then select new column