# Convert JSON ArrayType to MapType in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file in the below format that I am trying to read/query from spark job.

```
     {
        "dimensions": [

        {"id1":"val1"},
        {"id2":"val2"},
        {"id3":"val"}
         ...        
      ]     
    }


val schema = (new StructType).
                  add("dimensions",
                      new ArrayType(MapType(StringType,StringType),true))

val df = sparkContext.read.schema(schema).json(file)
```

'dimensions' is a JSON array and contains key value pair. I want to read it as just key-value pair (map) so that its easy to query in Spark SQL.

I tried above above schema, but it gives me array with each item being of MapType.
Is there a way to read the above json array as MapType?

In the end, I want to be able to write spark sql something like below where I can select individual keys:

```
val result = spark.sql("SELECT dimensions.id1, dimensions.id3 FROM table")
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain more its unclear

Comment: added more explanation in the original question.  Summary is - how can i convert array (each element in this array is a key-value pair) to a dictionary?

Comment: You can use the `explode()` function to convert the array of maps into rows of maps. It's not fully what you want, but your select query would work (returning 3 rows instead of 1). Another option may be to make the individual key/pairs into columns like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347098/pyspark-cast-array-with-nested-struct-to-string

Comment: Ended up writing a UDF to convert array of map to map.