# Convert Array with nested struct to string column along with other columns from the PySpark DataFrame

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

This is similar to [Pyspark: cast array with nested struct to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43347098/pyspark-cast-array-with-nested-struct-to-string)

But, the accepted answer is not working for my case, so asking here

```
|-- Col1: string (nullable = true)
|-- Col2: array (nullable = true)
    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
          |-- Col2Sub: string (nullable = true)
```

Sample JSON

```
{"Col1":"abc123","Col2":[{"Col2Sub":"foo"},{"Col2Sub":"bar"}]}
```

This gives result in a single column

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.selectExpr("EXPLODE(Col2) AS structCol").select(F.expr("concat_ws(',', structCol.*)").alias("Col2_concated")).show()
    +----------------+
    | Col2_concated  |
    +----------------+
    |foo,bar         |
    +----------------+
```

But, how to get a result or DataFrame like this

```
+-------+---------------+
|Col1   | Col2_concated |
+-------+---------------+
|abc123 |foo,bar        |
+-------+---------------+
```

**EDIT:**
This solution gives the wrong result

```
df.selectExpr("Col1","EXPLODE(Col2) AS structCol").select("Col1", F.expr("concat_ws(',', structCol.*)").alias("Col2_concated")).show() 


+-------+---------------+
|Col1   | Col2_concated |
+-------+---------------+
|abc123 |foo            |
+-------+---------------+
|abc123 |bar            |
+-------+---------------+
```

Comment: You can select "Col1", though it is not expression
df.selectExpr("Col1","EXPLODE(Col2) AS structCol").select("Col1", F.expr("concat_ws(',', structCol.*)").alias("Col2_concated")).show()

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work, I added the reason in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just avoid the explode and you are already there. All you need is the [concat_ws](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) function. This function concatenates multiple string columns with a given seperator. See example below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
j = '{"Col1":"abc123","Col2":[{"Col2Sub":"foo"},{"Col2Sub":"bar"}]}'
df = spark.read.json(sc.parallelize([j]))

#printSchema tells us the column names we can use with concat_ws                                                                              
df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- Col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Col2Sub: string (nullable = true)
```

The column Col2 is an array of Col2Sub and we can use this column name to get the desired result:

```
bla = df.withColumn('Col2', F.concat_ws(',', df.Col2.Col2Sub))

bla.show()
+------+-------+                                                                
|  Col1|   Col2|
+------+-------+
|abc123|foo,bar|
+------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks!, you are a lifesaver :)