# How to return several records in resulting RDD mapping one record in input RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

After several joins I've got an RDD which contains following records:

```
(Int, ((Int, Option[Iterable[Int]]), Option[Iterable[Int]]))
```

It is:

```
(id_of_client, ((id_of_order, products_in_order), all_products_client_ever_bought)
```

I need to transform it to (Int, Int, Boolean):

```
(id_of_order, all_products_client_ever_bought._1, was_this_product_in_this_order)
(id_of_order, all_products_client_ever_bought._2, was_this_product_in_this_order)
(id_of_order, all_products_client_ever_bought._3, was_this_product_in_this_order)
...
```

There should be as many, records in resulting RDD as there were items in all_products_client_ever_bought of all records of input RDD. So I'm mapping my input RDD, rdd.map(transform_df(_))

```
def transform_df(row: (Int, ((Int, Option[Iterable[Int]]), Option[Iterable[Int]]))) = {
    //(order_id, user_product_id, if_order_contains_product)
    val order_products = row._2._1._2.get.toList
    val user_products = row._2._2.get
    for (product_id <- user_products) {
        (row._2._1._1, product_id, order_products.contains(product_id))
    }
}
```

as a result I get RDD of the same length as input, but with empty tuples. How can I transform the RDD?

Comment: First try to give an explicit return type to `transform_df`. You should see that it is not what you probably expect it to be.

Comment: Yes, I see that it returns Unit, but this function was more like sketch to explain what I'm trying to do. I'm coming to the idea that I should have use explode (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906613/flattening-rows-in-spark) several steps before, and them make join, BUT is it possible at all to get bigger RDD after mapping, than the input one was?

Comment: That's what `flatMap` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need to "explode" your dataset, that is mapping each record to more than 1 records. With the RDD API, as well as in most functional programming languages, you need to use the flapMap function (explode is for dataframes).

See [map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/) for more detail on how to use flatmap. Basically, to each record of type A, you map a sequence of type Seq[B] and you get a RDD of type RDD[B] where everything is flattened out.

Another very convenient method in Spark is flatMapValue, with works on a pairRDD (key-value RDD) and only flattens the value.

In your example, you could first start by mapping your RDD to something that only contains what you need and which is more convenient to manipulate.

```
rdd.map{ case (id_of_client, ((id_of_order, products_in_order), all_products) 
           => id_of_order -> (products_in_order.get.toSet, all_products.get) }
```

Note BTW that using pattern matching instead of the ._1._2._2 notation is a good practice to make your code more readable. I also transformed the products of the order into a Set because we will need to make requests on it afterwards.

Then you would only need to use flatMapValues to get what you want.

```
.flatMapValues{ case (products_in_order, all_products) =>
        all_products.map(p => p -> product_in_order.contains(p)) }
.map { case (a,(b,c)) => (a,b,c) }
```

The last line only transforms the results into exactly what you wanted.