# Processing JSON containing nested entities using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, nested, spark-structured-streaming

I want to read nested data from Kafka topics source using Spark Structured Streaming. 
My Scala code (case classes and Spark processing code):

```
case class Nested(attr_int: Integer, attr_string: String, attr_float: Float, attr_timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp)

case class Parent(a_str: String, a_long: Long, a_nested: Array[Nested])


import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
val jsonSchema = Encoders.product[Parent].schema

val df = sparkSession
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "testnested")
    .option("group.id", "testnested")
    .option("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    .option("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    .load()
    .select($"value" cast "string" as "json")
    .select(from_json($"json", jsonSchema) as "data")
    .select("data.*")
    .withColumn("nested", explode($"a_nested"))
    .select("nested.*")
    .as[Nested]
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

When I send to Kafka data:

```
{"a_str":"Str","a_long":100,"a_nested":[{"attr_int":0,"attr_string":"nested_0","attr_float":0.0,"attr_timestamp":"2018-01-01T11:00:00.123321+02:00"},{"attr_int":1,"attr_string":"nested_1","attr_float":1.0,"attr_timestamp":"2018-02-02T12:01:01.023321+02:00"}]}
```

I get results:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+
|attr_int|attr_string|attr_float|      attr_timestamp|
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+
|       0|   nested_0|       0.0|2018-01-01 13:02:...|
|       1|   nested_1|       1.0|2018-02-02 14:01:...|
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+
```

Now I want to get each nested item joined to parent data, f.e.:

```
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------+
|attr_int|attr_string|attr_float|      attr_timestamp| a_str | a_long |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------+
|       0|   nested_0|       0.0|2018-01-01 13:02:...|   Str |    100 |
|       1|   nested_1|       1.0|2018-02-02 14:01:...|   Str |    100 |
+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------+-------+--------+
```

Note that `"a_str"` and `"a_long"` are columns from the parent entity `"Parent"`.
Since I'm not an expert in Spark Structured Streams processing, I want to know what is the most *"idiomatic"* approach to do it?
Currently I have assumptions:

1. Create custom Kafka value deserializer
2. Write some kind of join on structured streams (I stuck on it), but I suppose this will require changing json structure (f.e. specify in nested some key value
   pointing to a parent data)
3. Write custom method which will return denormalized data for joined entities and use `flatMap` with this method

Please advise.

Thanks

UPDATE 1: For your convenience I've created correspondent project on GitHub: https://github.com/lospejos/spark-nested-classes-from-json

Comment: It is because you are specifically writing `.select("nested.*").as[Nested]`, which will then only return the `nested`-columns. If you omit that I believe that you will get the `a_str` and `a_long` columns mapped onto your rows like you want :) (See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906613/flattening-rows-in-spark)

Comment: @GlennieHellesSindholt Thanks for reply. Unfortunately, if I omit `.as[Nested]` statement I'll get  the `a_nested` column, which contains complex structure inside, and I want to get all data of this column as a separate columns

Comment: Actually, if I omit just `as[Nested]` statement, I get nested entity in separate columns, but parent entity columns are lost. If I omit `select("nested.*").as[Nested]` statement, I get parent entity columns and nested entity one columns with complex data inside this column.

Comment: Ah, sorry - you want to write `.select($"nested.*", $"a_str", $"a_long")` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Glennie Helles Sindholt and for the benefit of other googlers:

```
.select($"nested.*", $"a_str", $"a_long")
```

Github repository also updated.